# Where can i get the .h file for OpenMP?

Tags: c, eclipse, openmp, parallel-processing

I'm searching for the `omp.h` file for using it in eclipse. I failed to find it in openmp.org.

Where do I find `omp.h`?

thanks.

Comment: Which OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: On Windows, it's not available in all editions of Visual Studio: ["OpenMP is not available in Visual C++ 2010 Express edition"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under Linux, you can find a file by

```
locate omp.h
```

Have you tried to simply use it with

```
#include <omp.h>
```

and add the openmp flag to your g++ compiler flag?

```
g++ -fopenmp sample.c
```

Comment: `$ locate omp.h | grep "^omp.h"` returns 0 results even though OpenMP is available. And `find /usr/include -name omp.h` returns 0 results, too.

Comment: @jww using `locate omp.h | grep "/omp.h"` returns 2 results for me. Using `^` does not work because full paths are returned.

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I find `omp.h`?

On Ubuntu 14:

```
$ find /usr -name omp.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/omp.h
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/include/omp.h
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's essentially a compiler builtin, so you won't find an actual header file for it. You do however need to use whatever flags the compiler uses for OpenMP.

Comment: You will still find the actual `omp.h` file, but only if the compiler is OpenMP-compatible.